# Read from ajax response

Tags: json, ajax

I receive this as a response from an ajax call. My question is how can I get the values of the object?

```
{"countries":[{"country_id":730,"country":"El Salvador"},{"country_id":756,"country":"Guatemala"},{"country_id":767,"country":"Indonesia"}]}
```

my ajax call is this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType:"json",
    url:getCountriesPackages,
    data: "transferUrl=countries?service_id="+serviceId,
    success: function(data) {

        $.each(data, function(k, v) {
          console.log(k);
        });
    }
});
```

thank you

Comment: `json_decode`, http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: First of all, `php` tag is not what you want. You say I *receive*, so this is happening in the browser, hence javascript. Then, it depends on how you make the ajax call. If you are using a jquery family of ajax calls, you are passing it a callback function that receives the object when the call is complete.

Comment: Help us help you. Post the code you currently use to make the ajax call. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have a JSON, you can traverse it using `$.each()`:

```js
var obj = {
  "countries": [{
    "country_id": 730,
    "country": "El Salvador"
  }, {
    "country_id": 756,
    "country": "Guatemala"
  }, {
    "country_id": 767,
    "country": "Indonesia"
  }]
};

$.each(obj, function(k, v) {
  $.each(v, function(kk, kv) {
    console.log("Country ID: " + kv.country_id);
    console.log("Country: " + kv.country);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, but actually I need to read it in jquery.

Comment: Why should the OP "just do"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Well because I thought it was obvious and easy in PHP, by just using `json_decode()`. Didn't knew, it was looking for JS version.

Answer (score 0):

Your response is a JavaScript object. We access attributes via the dot operator. Our first attribute returned is of type array. You can iterate through the array and access its' attributes for each element.

```
var response = {"countries":[{"country_id":730,"country":"El Salvador"},{"country_id":756,"country":"Guatemala"},{"country_id":767,"country":"Indonesia"}]};
var countries = response.countries;
for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
{
    var country_id = countries[i].country_id;
    var country = countries[i].country;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: okay will provide more.